# Why does F# find an error in my last line "disp" function?

Tags: f#

```
let disp xs (d:float) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> ' ' // return the space char
    | (a,b)::ts -> if(a > d)
                    then b // Found
                    else (disp ts d)
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to indicate recursive functions with `rec`:

```
let rec disp xs (d:float) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> ' ' // return the space char
    | (a,b)::ts -> if(a > d)
                    then b // Found
                    else (disp ts d)
```